# Change stacking order in ggplot stacked area graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-factor

I have the following data:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3)))
names(df) <- "cont_var"
df$factor_var <- as.factor(rep(c("fac1","fac2","fac3"),3))
df$prop <- c(10,20,70,20,30,50,25,40,35)
```

The levels of "factor_var" being:

```
> levels(df$factor_var)
[1] "fac1" "fac2" "fac3"
```

I make a stacked area plot using the following:

```
library(ggplot)
ggplot(df, aes(x=cont_var, y=prop, fill=factor_var)) +
  geom_area(colour="black",size=.2, alpha=.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "grey", "red"))
```

which returns the following result:
[image]

The legend shows "factor_var" ordered as per the levels seen before but the areas are not stacked in this same order. How can I produce an output with red at the bottom then grey then blue stacked on top as is the case in the legend?

(NB. This is the order I need (factor_var being an ordered variable), it is not just a case of matching the stacking to the legend order for aesthetic reasons.)

EDIT: Desired result shown below

[image]

SOLUTION !!

Reordering the dataframe is necessary to create the desired result:

```
newdata <- df[order(df$cont_var, df$factor_var),]
```

Many thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 6):

You could change the order of your legend by adding `guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))` to your code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=cont_var, y=prop, fill=factor_var)) +
  geom_area(colour="black",size=.2, alpha=.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "grey", "red")) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

this gives:

[image]

---

Alternatively, you can set the factor-levels before you plot:

```
# manually ordering the factor levels
dat$factor_var2 <- factor(dat$factor_var, levels=c("fac3","fac2","fac1"))
# automatcally ordering the factor levels (copied from Jakub P's answer)
dat$factor_var2 <- factor(dat$factor_var, sort(unique(dat$factor_var), decreasing = TRUE))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=cont_var, y=prop, fill=factor_var2)) +
  geom_area(colour="black",size=.2, alpha=.8) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "grey", "red"))
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: This works for the example above. However my real data is a bit more complicated - there are 9 levels which are in the correct order in the legend but are in fact plotted in the order (from bottom to top): level 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9. I'm sorry I cannot reproduce it exactly here, my data is sensitive.

Comment: With the update and `levels(dat$factor_var)`, the levels are in the order I would like for stacking, but level 5 is still plotted at the bottom!

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

```
df$factor_var <- rep(c("fac1","fac2","fac3"),3)
df$factor_var <- factor(df$factor_var, sort(unique(df$factor_var), decreasing = T))
```

On test data you proposed this produces consistent result of fac1 being red and at the bottom, etc.

Comment: As with Jaaps proposal, this reorders the factors as I would like to plot them, confirmed with `levels(df$factor_var)`, yet level 5 is still plotted at the bottom!

Comment: In the example given, in fact the values of fac3 should be at the bottom and fac1 at the top, it is not the orders of colours that needs to change but the order of values - see 2nd plot added (made by manipulating the values).

Comment: OK, I misunderstood you. Your solution (order the data.frame)makes me think of a general conclusion I came to a few months back: I had to sort factors, labels and data (all three) to get the desired result. Missing one of these was almost always leading to something messy in the chart.